# View differences between machines

Tags: spring, firefox, browser

I have a Spring application with PrimeFaces running on vagrant (Ubuntu 14.04). When I run the project on my machine and start FireFox (latest version) there are always display-errors. Do I start the project on a friends machine (same FireFox) everything works fine.

What can be the problem? Do I have to upload or set up something special?

Comment: What kind of errors does it display?

Comment: just graphical-errors by `class="fa fa-sign-out fa-4x"` for example.. the sign-out symbol doesn't show up

Comment: So if it works in one firefox and not in the other, it is not firefox related. And since you post **no** code (see [tour] and [ask], I'm inclined to vote to 'close'... And it is in this context not PrimeFaces or JSF related

Comment: I'm willing to post code, but what parts of the code? ... it completely works on my friends  machine with completely same application code and completely same vagrantfile .. i still think its related to my browser, because in Chrome there are more display-errors.. maybe I need some plugins?